Deriving differential equation for the path of a particle in potential $U(r)$ using Maupertuis’ principle
I came across this Maupertuis' principle in Landau and Lifshitz, which, in it's final form looks like $$\delta\int\sqrt{2m(E-U)}dl=0.\tag{44.10}$$
They used this equation to show that path of a free particle is a straight line which was fairly simple (putting $U=0$ will give us $\delta\int dl=0$ which shows that particle moves in a straight line).
In the problem on p. 142 they then tried to derive the differential equation for the general case where $U$ is non-zero. They proceeded in the following way $$\delta\int\sqrt{(E-U)}dl=-\int\{{\partial U \over \partial \mathbf r}.{\delta\mathbf r \over 2\sqrt{(E-U)}}dl-\sqrt{(E-U)}{d\mathbf r \over dl}\cdot d\delta\mathbf r\}.\tag{p.142}$$
They said that in the second term they used the fact that $dl^2=d\mathbf r^2$ and therefore $dl\ d\delta l=d\mathbf r\cdot d\delta \mathbf r$.
I have two questions regarding their approach:

What is $\mathbf r$ here and why is  $dl^2=d\mathbf r^2$?

Why is  $dl\ d\delta l=d\mathbf r\cdot d\delta \mathbf r$  if $dl^2=d\mathbf r^2$?



The $\mathbf r$ is the position variable of the particle, such that $\mathbf r(t)$ forms its trajectory. Mathematically, this function is a curve in $\mathbb R^3$, parametrized by the free parameter $t$.
The parameter $l$ is length. Usually, if we have two different points in the curve (corresponding to two different times) $\mathbf r(t)$ and $\mathbf r(t_0)$, we can calculate the distance of these two points as
$$
d= |\mathbf r(t) - \mathbf(t_0)|
$$
If we take the limit $t\rightarrow t_0$, the distance goes to zero. Now, if we divide it by the time interval and take the limit, we get a finite (non zero) quantity
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow t_0} {|\mathbf r(t)-\mathbf r(t_0)|\over t-t_0} = \left ({dl\over dt}\right)_{t_0}
$$
That we call the speed of the trajectory at the point $t_0$. It is not hard to check that speed is nothing more than the modulus of the vector velocity
$$
{d\mathbf r\over dt}\cdot {d\mathbf r\over dt} = \left({dl\over dt}\right)^2
$$
Now, the length of a curve between two arbitrary times is defined as the integral
$$
l = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} {dl\over dt} dt
$$
If we set $t_1=0$ and $t_2=t$, we can think about the above quantity as the total travelled length, and of course it is a function of time $l(t)$. It is not rare to find situations where the trajectory is parametrized as a function of $l$ instead of $t$ (sometimes $\mathbf r(l)$ is called path instead of trajectory).

In a non-rigorous manner, one could use this relations to write
$$
d\mathbf r \cdot d\mathbf r = dl^2
$$
Of course to turn it a little bit more rigorous we should consider the definition of differentials, like
$$
d\mathbf r = {d\mathbf r\over dt} dt
$$
And using it, you can check the relation above. To get the relation in your second question, we should differentiate the above expression, respecting the chain rule
$$
\delta (dl^2) = 2dl \delta (dl) = 2 dld\delta l
$$
You do the same for $d\mathbf r$ and you get what you want.

Thanks for answering. Can you please clarify how you wrote $\delta (dl^2) = 2dl \delta (dl) = 2 dld\delta l$

This is just the chain rule for derivative, and $\delta$ is a differential operator. If it is too abstract, you can change $\delta$ by some derivative like $\partial_t$ and the function $dl$ by the speed ${dl\over dt}$.

applying chain rule , i am getting $\delta (dl^2)= 2 \delta (l \ dl)=2[\delta l \ dl+l \ \delta (dl)]$

You should consider $dl$ as the function that you are applying the $\delta$ operator, not $l$.


The line element
$$ (\mathrm{d}\ell)^2~=~\sum_{i,k=1}^na_{ik} \mathrm{d}q^i\mathrm{d}q^k $$
in eq. (44.10) has metric tensor components $a_{ik}$ coming from the kinetic term
$$ T~=~\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,k=1}^n a_{ik} \dot{q}^i\dot{q}^k, \tag{p.141}$$
where $q^k$ are generalized positions.

In the problem on p. 142 L&L apparently specialize to where generalized positions $q^k$ are a point-particle position vector ${\bf r}$ with line element
$$ (\mathrm{d}\ell)^2~=~\mathrm{d}{\bf r} \cdot \mathrm{d}{\bf r}~=:~(\mathrm{d}{\bf r})^2,\tag{p.142}$$
and therefore by infinitesimal variation
$$  2\mathrm{d}\ell~\mathrm{d}\delta\ell 
~=~2\mathrm{d}\ell~\delta\mathrm{d}\ell
~=~\delta((\mathrm{d}\ell)^2)~=~\delta((\mathrm{d}{\bf r})^2)
~=~2\mathrm{d}{\bf r} \cdot \delta\mathrm{d}{\bf r}
~=~2\mathrm{d}{\bf r} \cdot \mathrm{d}\delta{\bf r}.\tag{p.142}$$



Firstly, it is a common thing in physics that $\vec r$ refers to the position vector. Usually, we get to assume that this position vector is the familiar Cartesian one, and is a function of time; $\vec r=\vec r(t)$
The potential energy function is $U=U(\vec r)$ and the variable labelled as $\ell$ is the arclength along the particle path, the very thing being varied. This means that $$\tag1\mathrm d\ell=\sqrt{\vec{\mathrm dr}\cdot\vec{\mathrm dr}}=\sqrt{\frac{\vec{\mathrm dr}}{\mathrm dt}\cdot\frac{\vec{\mathrm dr}}{\mathrm dt}}\ \mathrm dt$$
But this means that $\mathrm d\ell\,^2=\vec{\mathrm dr}\cdot\vec{\mathrm dr}$

Now, with all that out of the way, we can insert a path variation, which comes in as a $\delta$ on the path. Taking it on the square of the infinitesimal arclength, we see that it is reasonable that $2\,\mathrm d\ell\,\mathrm d\delta\ell=2\,\vec{\mathrm dr}\cdot\vec{\mathrm d\delta r}$
It is not very common nowadays to write $\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial\vec r}$; it is usually written these days as $\vec{\nabla U}$, and as such, the path variation thereof begets $\vec{\nabla U}\cdot\vec{\delta r}$
We are finally ready to figure out the whole thing. In $\delta\int\sqrt{E-U(\vec r)}\ \mathrm d\ell$, there is a term coming from $\delta$ acting on the $\mathrm d\ell$ and another coming from $\delta$ acting on $U(\vec r)$. Those are the two terms making up the integral that you typed up.
